# Examples for understanding the maximum modulus theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is a theorem in Conway's Book:

> Let $G$ be a region in $\mathbb{C}$ and $f$ an analytic function on $G$.Suppose there is a constant $M$ such that $\underset{z\rightarrow a}{\lim sup}\left| f\left( z \right) \right|\le M$ for all $a$ in $\partial_{\infty}G$.Then $\lvert f(z)\rvert\leq M$ for all $z$ in $G$

I want to find two eaxmples. One is used to show the effect of the thorem.Specifically,I want to find an anlytic function $f$:$$\underset{z\rightarrow a}{\lim sup}\left| f\left( z \right) \right|\ne \underset{z\rightarrow a}{\lim\text{in}f}\left| f\left( z \right) \right|$$

The other is to show the condition $\underset{z\rightarrow a}{\lim sup}\left| f\left( z \right) \right|
$ can not be weaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For point $2$,if there is an $a$ on the boundary of $G$ (including $\infty$ if $G$ unbounded) and $\underset{z\rightarrow a}{\lim sup}\left| f\left( z \right) \right|=M>0$, (where $M$ could be infinite too), then by the defintion of $\limsup$, there are points:

$z_n \in G, z_n \to a, |f(z_n)| \ge M-1/n$

By maximum modulus it follows that $|f(z)| > M-1/n$ in $G$ hence $|f(z)| \ge M$ there, so $|f(z)|$ cannot be bounded by any number that is strictly less than some such $\limsup$

For point $1$ for example one can take $G$ the unit disc and $f(z)=\frac{1-e^{-\frac{1+z}{1-z}+1}}{e-e^{-\frac{1+z}{1-z}}}$

It is clear that $|f(z)| < 1, |z|<1$ since $|e^{-\frac{1+z}{1-z}}|<1$ in the unit disc (as $\Re \frac{1+z}{1-z} >0$ there) so the function $f(z)$ is of the type $\frac{a-w(z)}{1-\bar a w(z)}$ with $a=1/e, w(z)=e^{-\frac{1+z}{1-z}}$ and $|a|, |w(z)|<1$

Note that as $r \to 1, 0<r<1$ one has $e^{-\frac{1+r}{1-r}} \to 0$ so $f(r) \to 1/e$ but also that $f$ has infinitely many zeroes in the unit disc at $z_k=\frac{ik\pi}{ik\pi+1}, k \in \mathbb Z$. Clearly $z_k \to 1, |k| \to \infty$ also and $f(z_k) = 0$ so the inferior limit of $|f|$ when $z \to 1$ is $0$ and the superior limit is $\ge 1/e$

(for the zeroes, one needs to solve $\frac{1+z}{1-z}=1+2ik\pi, z=\frac{ik\pi}{ik\pi+1}, k \in \mathbb Z$ and all the roots are inside the unit disc